# ¿Comó funciona la paginación en CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paginación

Buen dia, tengo un problema con mi paginación realizada en codeigiter

[image: Páginación CodeIgniter]
al dar click para que me muestre los siguientes datos cambia la URL pero no me muestra los datos siguientes.[image: al dar click a la siguiente pagina]

Método de la paginación

```
  public function consulta_miembros()
```

{

```
        $data['tipo']="Miembro";

        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] =base_url('Ver_Miembros/');
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->M_Registro->getNumMiembros();
        $config['per_page']=10;
        $config['uri_segment']=3;
        $config['num_links']=20;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul style="color:#fff" class="pagination justify-content-center">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['consulta']= $this->M_Registro->getPafinacion($config['per_page']);
        $data['pagination_n']=$this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('V_Consultas',$data);
```

}

Rutas CodeIgniter

```
$route['Ver_Miembros/(:any)']='C_Registro/consulta_miembros/$1';
$route['Ver_Miembros']='C_Registro/consulta_miembros';
```

Método del modelo

```
public function getPafinacion($numero_por_pagina)
    {
            $this->db->order_by('codigo_miembro', 'ASC');
            return $this->db->get('tb_miembros',$numero_por_pagina,$this->uri->segment(3));
    }
```

Comment: Anthony, bienvenido a SOes. Antes de darte mis puntos, te recomiendo hacer el [tour]. 1. Podrias poner el metodo `getPafinacion` de tu modelo `M_Registro`? Esta muy relacionado a todo esto. 2. En tu ruta, con `$1` indicas que vas a pasar ese parametro a la funcion `consulta_miembros`, pero en el controlador el espacio entre parentesis para los parametros esta vacio, esto sera necesario para saber cual es la siguiente porcion de personas que necesitas en la proxima pagina.

Comment: Aparte de lo que te recomienda Kenny puede [edi] pregunta y poner el codigo en texto es para que se pueda probar de forma mas facil.

Comment: Y por favor, tenemos un muy buen editor de codigo. Considera reemplazar tus capturas de pantalla por codigo. Puedes hacer todo esto desde la opcion [edit] de la pregunta.

Comment: @KennyBarrera gracias por los consejos, ya edite la pregunta

Comment: Hola, en tu controlador tienes que recibir el parametro que estas enviando de tu url `public function consulta_miembros( $page = 0 ){`

Comment: Anthony, creo que ya se que esta pasando, dame un momento que en este momento no puedo escribir la respuesta.

Comment: @elddenmedio, hola según eso lo hace `uri->segment(3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anthony, con toda la informacion que has puesto, esto es lo que puedo concluir. Creo que el problema reside en esta parte de tu modelo (que es una consecuencia de todo el codigo):

```
return $this->db->get('tb_miembros',$numero_por_pagina,$this->uri->segment(3));
```

Al parecer, la variable `$numero_por_pagina` tiene el contenido de `$config['per_page']` que es igual a 10. Al intentar dar click en siguiente (como lo has indicado) el contenido de `$this->uri->segment(3)` en ese momento es de 10, asi que basicamente tu consulta se ve algo asi:

```
return $this->db->get('tb_miembros',10,10);
```

Que traducido se veria algo asi

```
SELECT * FROM tb_miembros LIMIT 10, 10;
```

Y que mas traducido se veria algo asi

```
SELECT * FROM tb_miembros LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;
```

Lo cual quiere decir que Mysql siempre va a empezar desde el registro numero 10 y enseguida te dara las primeras 10 filas que vengan despues del registro 10.

Ahora bien, esto no tiene nada de malo, pero piensalo bien. Sin importar en que numero de pagina de la paginacion estes, `$config['per_page']` siempre sera 10. Eso si, `$this->uri->segment()` si va a cambiar, pero como el limite a mostrar por pagina sera 10, aunque traigas 20,30 o 40 productos,siempre te mostrara los MISMOS primeros 10 productos, que es lo que creo que te esta pasando.

Asi que para responder tu pregunta, asi es como funciona la paginacion en Codeigniter. Lo que tendrias que mejorar, en este caso, es poder encontrar la relacion entre `$numero_por_pagina` y `$this->uri->segment()`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si tenia que ver con el `uri->segment()`, al parecer al recuperar el `uri->segment()` en la posición 3 estaba vacia.
1-> localhost/ascender no cuenta como posición en el `uri->segment()`
2-> Ver_Miembros/ es la posición 1
3-> / , /10 viene siendo la posición 2 no la tres

aún así muchas gracias.

Comment: Correcto, la primera vez que se renderiza la vista en esa posicion no hay nada. No lo mencione porque supuse que ya lo habrias notado para entonces. Espero y se resuelva todo! Saludos.

Comment: si ya esa funcionando correctamente, solo falta agregarle correctamente los estilos de bootstrap

Comment: Que bien. Te invito a seguir activo en el sitio y ayudar a mas personas de acuerdo a tu tiempo y capacidades. Saludos!